# KnockOut Array Binding To A Single Index

Tags: javascript, cordova, knockout.js, devextreme

so I have my observable array

```
answer: ko.observableArray("")
```

and I'm trying to use data-bind to access just answer()[0]

```
<div id="iAnswer" style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 80%; border: 0px;"
                     data-bind="dxTextBox: { value: answer()[$data.index], text:$data.answer}"></div>
```

$data.index is equal to 0 when its getting passed through.

Comment: Can you please show the full code including the data that is in the answer array. This isn't enough to see an issue

Comment: There isn't any data in the array, sometimes there is data, but the majority of the time it will  be empty.  The issue is how to data-bind just 1 index to the textbox.  Its being loaded dynamically using a multiview in devextreme.  Heres the done on paste bin   http://pastebin.com/1aWJdrWb    http://pastebin.com/YcDjFVh4

Comment: How can you access an index of the array if there is no elements in the array?

Comment: Are you trying to add one answer that it empty string?

Comment: array[0] <-- even though that is empty it should still return with nothing.  I dont mind receiving an empty array, in fact that is anticipated. The problem is I'm recieving an error.

Comment: Where is $data.index coming from? Are you in a loop

Comment: dxTemplate creates $data.  dxMultiview creates views based on the data source its given, and it creates these views using dxTemplate to model it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code solve your task?

```
<!-- ko if: answer().length === 0 -->
    <div> There are no answers. </div>
<-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: answer().length === 0 -->
<div id="iAnswer" style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 80%; border: 0px;"
          data-bind="dxTextBox: { text:$data.answer }"></div>                
<-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Actually, I wasn't properly initializing the KO observables and my values weren't changing. I figured it out, thanks though.